# Algebra subgroup question

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Let $G$ be a group, and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Define $$C_G(H) := \lbrace g \in G \mid h \in H :gh=hg \rbrace.$$
(The set $C_G(G)$ is called the centralizer of $H$ in $G$.) Show that $C_G(H)$ is a subgroup of $G$.

We have that $gh \in C_G(H)$ so the 1st condition of a subgroup holds. The 2nd condition states that $(gh)^{-1}$ must also be in $C_G(H)$ and indeed it is since $g^{-1} \in H$ and $h^{-1} \in H$ so that $(gh)^{-1}=g^{-1}h^{-1}$. Therefore $C_G(H)$ is indeed a subgroup of $G$ as well.

Is this the  correct way to go about proving this? Did I leave any gaps? I just want to know if there was a better way to prove this or a shorter way of doing it.

Comment: You probably should verify in detail that if $H$ and $g$ are in the centralizer of $H$, then so is $hg$. Notationally, it may be less confusing to show that if $g_1$ and $g_2$ are in the centralizer, so is $g_1g_2$. Also with the inverse, detailed checking is a good idea.

Comment: Good idea I will take that into consideration! Now for the inverse, isn't it quite obvious that the product of the inverses is also in $H$?

Comment: We need to show that if $g$ commutes with every element of $H$, then so does $g^{-1}$. This is not hard to show, but at this stage of the game I would not call it obvious.

Comment: Isn't $g$ the definition of the neutral element?

Comment: No it is not. The object $g$ is an arbitrary element of the centralizer of $H$. It need not be the neutral element. It is indeed obvious that the neutral element is in the centralizer.

Comment: @adam no, notice that the neutral element is defined as the $e$ so that any $a$ we have $ae = ea = a$, but we only have the condition that $gh = hg$, not necessarily that last equality. For example take $\mathbb{Z}_37$ (both $G = H = \mathbb{Z}_37$) and consider $g=5$.

Comment: If I multiply both sides by $g^{-1}$ should get the equality of $h=h$ so does that imply that $g^{-1}$ must also be in the centralizer for the equality to hold?

Comment: By the way, your definition of the centralizer is technically not correct. The centralizer is the set of all $g\in G$ such that $gh=hg$ for *all* $h\in H$.

Comment: well I guess the professor wrote it down wrong I was going by what he wrote. I guess thats why I ran into a problem

Comment: Let $h\in H$. Then $h^{-1}\in H$. Thus $gh^{-1}=h^{-1}g$. Take the inverse of both sides. We get $hg^{-1}=g^{-1}h$.

Comment: ahhhh I see it now just use the definition of the centralizer and take $h^{-1}$ instead of $h$. Is this the only inconsistency here?

Comment: I changed a bit, does this sound better? The 2nd condition states that $(gh)^{-1}$ must also be in $C_G(H)$ and indeed it is since $gh^{-1}=h^{-1}g \in H$. We must also have that $g^{-1}h=hg^{-1} \in C_G(H)$ so $g^{-1} \in C_G(H)$ which means that $g^{-1}h^{-1}$ is also in $C_G(H)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to show that $C_G(H)$ is closed under the group operation and to show that :

if $g_1$ and $g_2$ belong to $C_G(H)$,where $g_1$ and $g_2$ are in $G$ then $g_1h=hg_1$ and $g_2h=hg_2$ for all $h \in H$.

Now $g_1g_2h=g_1(g_2h)=g_1hg_2=(g_!h)g_2=hg_1g_2$ for all $h \in H$
Hence $g_1g_2 \in C_G(H)$.

Clearly $e \in C_G(H)$ as $eh=he$ forall $h \in H$
For inverse observe that once $g_1 \in C_G(H)$, $g_1h=hg_1$ foral $h \in H$. Hence $g_1^{-1}h=hg_1^{-1}$ forall $h \in H$

Comment: What is $g_1$ and $g_2$ are not coming from $G$ I hope. It's not making sense since the way $C_G(H)$ is defined, only 1 element in $G$ is chosen such that the following condition holds not $\forall g$ hence taking 2 elements $g_1$ and $g_2$ wouldn't work

Comment: since $g_1$ and $g_2$ are arbitary elements it works